# How to divide column values by values from different row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe (`df`):

```
                       value1 value2 total
Index1 Index2 Index3     
  A0     B0     C0       10     15    25
                C1       11     12    23
                C2       1      2     3
  A1     B1     C0       2      3     5
                C1       3      4     7
                C2       4      5     9
      ...
```

What I want to do is to divide `value1` and `value2` by `total` only if the value of `Index3` is `C0`.

In the case of `C1` and `C2`, `value1` and `value2` must be divided by `value1` and `value2` where `Index3` is `C0`, respectively.

As a result, new dataframe must be:

```
                       value1 value2 total
Index1 Index2 Index3     
  A0     B0     C0      10/25  15/25  25
                C1      11/10  12/15  23
                C2       1/10   2/15   3
  A1     B1     C0       2/5    3/5    5
                C1       3/2    4/3    7
                C2       4/2    5/3    9
      ...
```

How to achieve this complex operation?

Comment: Show us the (trivial) `df.iterrows()` solution, please. And then we can all examine whether it is worth it to move it to a pure pandas solution. (Likely three pandas operations.) Also, consider defining several "denominator" columns.

Comment: @J_H what do you mean by 'show us the `df.iterrows()` solution? The dataframe is multiindexed dataframe (`Index1`, `Index2`,`Index3`). I also tried to define 'denominator' columns, but I couldn't find out a way to get column values from different row where `Index3` is `C0`.

Comment: I mean, for an individual row containing (index3, value1, value2, total) values, your narrative makes it clear how to compute value1bis and value2bis. (I'm trying to prefer a functional approach over a mutable approach here.) With that code in hand, it becomes easier to talk about using pandas functions to achieve same result. For one thing, the unit tests can simply verify the two competing implementations produce identical results.  I was hoping to help you break the problem into simpler sub-problems. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: @J_H Thank you. Due to the multiindex, the problem becomes more difficult for me to solve. `df.iterrows()` shows `((A0, B0, C0), value1 10 value2 15 total 25)`, `((A0, B0, C1), value1 11, value2 12, total 23)`, ...

Comment: @sungjuncho I defined "denominator" columns in the solution I posted. I tried to make it easy to read.

Comment: Kindly share the dataframe as a dictionary `df.to_dict()` so that it is reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare denominator columns based on your requirements:

1. If `Index3 == 'C0'`, divide by `total`.
2. Otherwise, divide by the value where `Index3 == 'C0'`.

```py
# Reset index to be able to reference `Index` columns more easily
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Create catalog of divisors for cases when `Index3 == 'C0'`
cat = df.loc[
    df['Index3'].eq('C0'),
    ['Index1','Index2','value1','value2']
].rename(columns={'value1':'div1', 'value2':'div2'})

# Merge data with catalog
df = pd.merge(df, cat, on=['Index1','Index2'], how='inner')

# Update divisors when `Index3 == 'C0'
df[['div1', 'div2']] = df[['div1', 'div2']].apply(
    lambda x: np.where(
        df['Index3'] == 'C0', df['total'], x
    )
)

# Restore multi index
df.set_index(['Index1', 'Index2', 'Index3'], inplace=True)
```

The data now looks as follows:

```py
                      value1  value2  total  div1  div2
Index1 Index2 Index3                                   
A0     B0     C0          10      15     25    25    25
              C1          11      12     23    10    15
              C2           1       2      3    10    15
A1     B1     C0           2       3      5     5     5
              C1           3       4      7     2     3
              C2           4       5      9     2     3
```

So you only have to divide `value1` by `div1` and `value2` by `div2`:

```py
# Update `value1` and `value2` by diviging by its corresponding divisor column
df['value1'] = df['value1'] / df['div1']
df['value2'] = df['value2'] / df['div2']
```

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution and techniques used in the solution are helpful to do other similar work. Thank you! By the way, is the order of rows from `reset_index` preserved?

Comment: Hi @sungjuncho! Yes, the order is preserved when you use `reset_index`. The only thing that changes is that the indices are treated as values (which is why the empty spaces are filled).